# Pie Chart Variations

Tags: highcharts

We have been using Highcharts in our tool for a couple years now, and we want to generate some pie charts in a new fashion. Does anyone know if it's possible to build something like this in Highcharts? If so, can you send me to any examples?

[image: Pie Chart Example]

Comment: The chart presented seems to be a very simple one and you should be able to figure out by yourself or at least try it and recur to the site if you can't achieve.

Comment: It looks like a regular pie chart. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend Could you describe what is a particular problem which you are struggling to?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to display the legend to the left of the pie and how to insert free-form text of varying sizes like in the example I posted. Any feedback on those types of customizations?

Comment: You should be able to position legend by using standard API options: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend and to render a custom text, use the SVG Renderer tool: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer and here is a base demo which you can start from: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hp50nfaj/